# ReactJS router v4 Mobx - Router wont re-render components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use mobx `Provider` to provide stores, by wrapping the `Router`

```
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <BrowserRouter >
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

In `App` I have two components, `Header` and `Main`.
`Header` contains `Link` to the routes and `Main` contains the routes `Switch`:

```
  <div className="main">
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
      {/* <UnvalidatedUserRoute exact path='/login' store={this.props.User} component={Login} /> */}
      <ValidatedUserRoute exact path='/todos' store={this.props.User} component={UserTodos} />
  </div>
```

`ValidatedUserRoute` is just a function that makes sure the user is authenticated, if not, redirect to home.

```
 const ValidatedUserRoute = ({component: Component}, store, ...rest) => (
    <Route 
      {...rest} 
      render={props => 
        store.validated ? (
        <Component {...props} />) : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: "/"
          }}
          />
        )
    } />
  );
  export default ValidatedUserRoute
```

**The problem**

When I click on the links, **my URL does change**, but the components does not render, like the page is stuck on what component was loaded at first when loading the web-page.

```
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to='/login'>Log In</Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using the new `react-router-dom`. then you have to use a `withRouter` Hoc given by the library and wrap your component with it.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

const ValidatedUserRoute = ({component: Component}, store, ...rest) => (
    <Route 
      {...rest} 
      render={props => 
        store.validated ? (
        <Component {...props} />) : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: "/"
          }}
          />
        )
    } />
  );
  export default withRouter(ValidatedUserRoute)
```

what ever component is responsible for performing routing. wrap that in `withRouter`

Comment: Do I have to wrap all components with this or only the components thats containing the routes?

Comment: all the components that are causing the route changes. it can be `Header` also.